# Странная фигурная скобка на странице настроек

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, настройки-профиля

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну razor же))) Хотя точка с запятой была бы более классическим вариантом)

Comment: А на MSE еще нет такого дефекта опубликованного? Я предпочитаю не писать на ruSO, если проблема глобальна. Хотя бывают и исключения.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328573/260198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [комментарию](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328573/there-is-an-unwanted-close-curly-brace-in-the-preferences-page#comment1072867_328573) разработчика, в dev ветке пофиксили. В ближайшее время выкатят. Предположительно во вторник.